# Encrypting & mounting directory with ecryptfs

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs

I wanted to encrypt a directory in such a way that the directory will stay encrypted after I login and only when I deliberately enter my passphase will the content of the directory be decrypted.  I did the following

```
mkdir ./secret
chmod 700 secret
sudo mount -t ecryptfs ./secret ./secret
```

Answered all the questions with sensible answers and check with

```
>mount |grep secret
/home/myname/mydir/secret on /home/myname/mydir/secret type ecryptfs (rw,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=xxxxxx,ecryptfs_sig=yyyyyy,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

and then placed some files into ./secret , checked the files are accessible (which is suppose to be).  Then I unmount the directory so that it stays encrypted.

```
sudo umount ./secret
```

Checked again now all the files are encrypted (also filenames). Then I want to access the files I tried to mount it back using the following line

```
sudo mount ./secret ./secret -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes
```

But I got a

```
mount: /home/myname/mydir/secret: /home/myname/mydir/secret is not a block device.
```

Did I missing something when first setup the mount point?

Comment: You mounted it on top of itself... that's rather confusing, especially for testing

Comment: This should not have been closed.

Answer (score 3):

OK after studying a bit I realized for my case I need to specify the -t ecryptfs again in my mount command:

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs ./secret ./secret -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes
```

And then it worked.